# Not able to run Batch Script from TFS

Tags: xaml, tfs

I am not able to run batch script from TFS XAML build, its giving Access Denied error. But I am able to run the same script from the build server manually itself. How to solve it? Build server has administrator rights and given full control on Drives.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the **build agent service account** has the permission to run the cmd.exe and has the permission to access to the path/directory specified in the batch script.

You can try to add the agent service account to **administrator local group** of build server or to **domain administrator global group**. And give the permission to access the path/directory for the agent service account.

Please reference below link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/867466/-access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-run-a-batch-job-on-a-windows-server-2003-based-computer

Comment: It is solved.Build service was not configured with admin account :)

Comment: @Priya.D Glad to know that you have resolved the issue, could you please Mark it as Answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread, thanks for your understanding.